# How can I render a form after a button is clicked in Colorbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, render, colorbox

I'm trying implement a button inside a Colorbox that will update the modal and render a form.

An example of this is Pinterest's add functionality. ["Homepage > Add a Pin > Pin URL"](http://pinterest.com)

I've tried copying Colorbox's inline HTML example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});

    $('a[rel="colorbox"]').live("click", function() {

    $.colorbox({
        open: true,
        href: this.href
    });

    return false;
    });
});
</script>

        <div style='display:none'>
            <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
            <p><strong>Add a Promotion</strong></p>
            <p><a id="click" href="#" style='padding:5px; background:#ccc;'>Click me, it will be preserved!</a></p>
            <p><strong>If you try to open a new ColorBox while it is already open, it will update itself with the new content.</strong></p>
            <p>Updating Content Example:<br />
            <a class="ajax" href="**shared/promotion_form**" rel="colorbox">Add a Promotion</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is that the form is _promotion_form.html.erb so I can't link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your selector up a level, and updating to jQuery 1.7.1
Maybe something like this:

`$('body').on("click", "a[rel="colorbox"]", function() {`

So this way you're watching the body for any element that has that selector "a[rel='colorbox']".

Hope this helps.

Comment: The selector works right now. What I'm having problems with is I don't know how to render the promotion form instead of linking via href.

Comment: Oh.... just use the html property instead of the href property and the value will be a string, or a jQuery Object.